# "Correct" Dialog / UI font on Windows

Tags: windows, user-interface, winapi, fonts

When creating a control (e.g. an edit control) on the fly using CreateWindow, it usually starts out with an ugly (boldish sans serif) font.

Usually I wok around that by grabbing the parent dialog's font, and setting it to the control - I can't even say if this is a good idea.

How do I "legally" fetch the right font?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The "correct" way to get the font used in dialog boxes like message boxes, etc. would be via the `SystemParametersInfo()` function:

```
// C++ example
NONCLIENTMETRICS metrics;
metrics.cbSize = sizeof(NONCLIENTMETRICS);
::SystemParametersInfo(SPI_GETNONCLIENTMETRICS, sizeof(NONCLIENTMETRICS),
    &metrics, 0);
HFONT font = ::CreateFontIndirect(&metrics.lfMessageFont);
::SendMessage(ctrlHWND, WM_SETFONT, (WPARAM)font, MAKELPARAM(TRUE, 0));
```

Don't forget to destroy the font when the controls are destroyed:

```
::DeleteObject(font);
```

You can look up the MSDN documentation for [`NONCLIENTMETRICS`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff625302(VS.85).aspx) and [`SystemParametersInfo()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724947(VS.85).aspx) to see what other system-wide parameters you can retrieve.

Comment: Thanks!
(I'm putting it into a CHandleRef, no chance to forget a delete! - http://www.codeproject.com/KB/stl/boostsp_handleref.aspx)