# win32 - Using the default button font in a button

Tags: c++, winapi, fonts

I'm creating a small WinAPI application in C++. I am trying to create a button on my form by using the code:

```
HWND hwndButton = CreateWindow(
    TEXT("BUTTON"),   
    TEXT("Click Here"),       
    WS_TABSTOP | WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | BS_PUSHBUTTON,  // Styles 
    10,         
    10,         
    100,        
    30,        
    hwnd,     
    NULL,       
    (HINSTANCE)GetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_HINSTANCE),
    NULL);
```

This code is based off of an MSDN sample. My issue is that it uses a bold font on the button like this:

[image]

When I want to use the standard font like this:

[image]

I already have the preprocessor directive at the top of my file to enable visual styles.

```
#pragma comment(linker,"\"/manifestdependency:type='win32' \
name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' \
processorArchitecture='*' publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' language='*'\"")
```

What steps should I take to use the standard system wide font?

Thanks

Comment: You have to set the font yourself see link http://stackoverflow.com/a/2942869/4603670

Comment: OK. Thanks. Out of curiosity, Why is the system wide font not used by default?

Comment: I don't know why that ugly font is used as default, instead of the font which everybody wants. Maybe it's for backward compatibility.

Comment: By the way, the dialog box above uses a different font. If target platform is Vista and above then you can go to dialog editor and use "Segoe UI" size 9 pt, or manage the font in `WM_INITDIALOG`

Comment: [Which font is the default, and how do I get it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6057239/which-font-is-the-default-for-mfc-dialog-controls/6057761#6057761)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no such thing as default system wide font for controls, initially you get a control created with "System" font, that's what you see on first picture. When button is created as part of a dialog, it uses a font from dialog template, so using something like "MS Shell Dlg" with appropriate size + WM_SETFONT on a button should give you the same result as on picture 2. Note that there's no physical MS Shell Dlg font on a system, it's mapped to particular font according to registry settings.

Common control manifest has nothing to do with this, behavior has not changed with comctl32 version 6.

Answer (score 7):

[GetStockObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vs/alm/dd144925(v=vs.85).aspx) isn't the recommended way of retrieving the GUI font (it doesn't take themes into account, and different fonts can be chosen for buttons, menus, etc). Instead you should use [SystemParametersInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724947.aspx) (see *Remarks* section of `GetStockObject`).

> It is not recommended that you employ this method to obtain the current font used by dialogs and windows. Instead, use the SystemParametersInfo function with the SPI_GETNONCLIENTMETRICS parameter to retrieve the current font. SystemParametersInfo will take into account the current theme and provides font information for captions, menus, and message dialogs.

```
NONCLIENTMETRICS metrics = {};
metrics.cbSize = sizeof(metrics);
SystemParametersInfo(SPI_GETNONCLIENTMETRICS, metrics.cbSize, &metrics, 0);

HFONT guiFont = CreateFontIndirect(&metrics.lfCaptionFont);

// When you're done with the font, don't forget to call
DeleteObject(guiFont);
```

Answer (score 2):

The default GUI font is stored in `DEFAULT_GUI_FONT`, and can be retrieved via

```
GetStockObject(DEFAULT_GUI_FONT);
```

To set the font of the button you can use:

```
HWND yourButton; // use CreateWindow or anything else to get this
SendMessage(yourButton, WM_SETFONT, (LPARAM)GetStockObject(DEFAULT_GUI_FONT), true);
```

Comment: `SystemParametersInfo` is recommended over `GetStockObject`.

Answer (score 1):

A convenient way of doing this without calling `SendMessage` on every single child window manually is to use the `EnumChildWindows` function with the following callback function -

1. Create the callback function `EnumChildProc`:

   ```
    BOOL CALLBACK EnumChildProc(
        HWND hWnd,
        LPARAM lParam
    )
    {
        HFONT hfDefault = *(HFONT *) lParam;
        SendMessageW(hWnd, WM_SETFONT, (WPARAM) hfDefault, MAKELPARAM(TRUE, 0));
        return TRUE;
    }
   ```
2. At the start of your `(w)WinMain` function, add the code:

   ```
    NONCLIENTMETRICSW ncm;
    HFONT hfDefault;

    ZeroMemory(&ncm, sizeof(NONCLIENTMETRICSW));
    ncm.cbSize = sizeof(NONCLIENTMETRICSW);

    SystemParametersInfo(SPI_GETNONCLIENTMETRICS, sizeof(NONCLIENTMETRICS), &ncm, FALSE);
    hfDefault = CreateFontIndirectW(&ncm.lfMessageFont);
   ```

   Then, after the `ShowWindow` call, add this line:

   ```
    EnumChildWindows(hWnd, EnumChildProc, (LPARAM)&hfDefault);
   ```

Comment: You are a hero.